# Validar hora_pedido y hora_entrega para que sea mayor a 24 horas, con modelos diferentes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A partir de la hora actual, necesito validar que sea mayor a 24 horas:

- `hora_pedido` es hora inicial.
- `hora_entrega` es hora final.

Del modelo padre, hay un atributo llamado `hora_pedido`; modelo:

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord

 #maestro de detalle 
 has_many :detalles_reuniones, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :detalles_reuniones, allow_destroy: true

 def detalles_reuniones_for_form
   collection = detalles_reuniones.where(reunion_id: id)
   collection.any? ? collection : detalles_reuniones.build
 end


     #El metodo que asigna los valores
    before_validation :asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion

   def asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion
    Time.zone = "America/Bogota"
   self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
 end
```

Del modelo hijo, hay un atributo llamado `hora_entrega`; modelo  class

```
class DetalleReunion < ApplicationRecord

    #Asociaccion por maestro de detalle
    belongs_to :reunion, optional: true

   validate :validar_horas 

   def validar_horas
     if ( hora_entrega - ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) >= ( reunion.hora_pedido )
     # Código cuando se cumple la condición
     else
      errors.add(:hora_entrega," La entrega debe ser mayor a 24  horas  ")
    end
   end       
end
```

Los dos atributos son de tipo `Time`:

- `hora_pedido` = `Time`
- `hora_entrega` = `Time`

Es un maestro detalle, son dos formularios llenados  a las vez entonces en la tabla padre hay un atributo que es `hora_pedido`, esta sería la hora actual y en la tabla hija hay un atributo que es `hora_entrega` es la hora, para definir la   que sea mayor a las  24 horas, la tabla padre se llama `reunion` y la tabla hija `detalle_reunion`.

**Ya actualicé todo el código**:

**LOG**

```
  Started POST "/reuniones" for 200.47.156.216 at 2017-06-09 15:38:30 +0000
  Cannot render console from 200.47.156.216! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  Processing by ReunionesController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NXxV3OeCmrzYCMB6ZoVxWuFArqnjgpvjAnFHA84NVOwFd3hRehH0TtWPjfICry/4Nhmpi+zkL6cgmsEA2wIrHw==", 
   "reunion"=>{"detalles_reuniones_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"
    producto_id"=>"", 
    "cantidad"=>"",
    "valor"=>"", 
    "hora_entrega(1i)"=>"2017", 
    "hora_entrega(2i)"=>"6", 
    "hora_entrega(3i)"=>"9", 
    "hora_entrega(4i)"=>"03", 
    "hora_entrega(5i)"=>"38", 
    "_destroy"=>"false"}}, 
    "subtotal"=>"", 
    "hora_inicio(1i)"=>"2017", 
    "hora_inicio(2i)"=>"6", 
    "hora_inicio(3i)"=>"9", 
    "hora_inicio(4i)"=>"10", 
    "hora_inicio(5i)"=>"38", 
    "hora_final(1i)"=>"2017", 
    "hora_final(2i)"=>"6", 
    "hora_final(3i)"=>"9", 
    "hora_final(4i)"=>"10", 
    "hora_final(5i)"=>"38", 
    "fecha_entrega"=>"09/06/2017", 
    "planta_id"=>"", 
    "centro_costo_fullname"=>"", 
    "ubicacion"=>"", 
    "observacion"=>""}, 
    "commit"=>"Crear Reunion"}
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 Rendering reuniones/new.html.erb within layouts/application
 Producto Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "productos".* FROM "productos"
 Rendered reuniones/_detalle_reunion_fields.html.erb (8.1ms) [cache miss]
 CACHE Producto Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "productos".* FROM "productos"
 Rendered reuniones/_detalle_reunion_fields.html.erb (6.6ms) [cache miss]
 Planta Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "plantas".* FROM "plantas"
 Rendered reuniones/_form.html.erb (30.7ms) [cache miss]
 Rendered reuniones/new.html.erb within layouts/application (31.8ms)
 Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.7ms) [cache miss]
 Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.9ms) [cache miss]
 Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms) [cache miss]
 Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 187.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

***ignore los otros atributos  no necesarios ****

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
create_table "detalles_reuniones", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time "hora_entrega"
  t.integer "cantidad"
  t.integer "reunion_id"
  t.integer "producto_id"
  t.integer "evento_interno_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "valor"
  t.index ["evento_interno_id"], name: " 
  index_detalles_reuniones_on_evento_interno_id"
  t.index ["producto_id"], name: "index_detalles_reuniones_on_producto_id"
  t.index ["reunion_id"], name: "index_detalles_reuniones_on_reunion_id"
end

create_table "reuniones", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time "hora_pedido"
  t.date "fecha_pedido"
  t.time "hora_inicio"
  t.time "hora_final"
  t.date "fecha_entrega"
  t.string "observacion"
  t.integer "subtotal"
  t.integer "planta_id"
  t.integer "centro_costo_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "ubicacion"
  t.index ["centro_costo_id"], name: "index_reuniones_on_centro_costo_id"
  t.index ["planta_id"], name: "index_reuniones_on_planta_id"
end
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué es lo que estás buscando?, ¿Podrías proporcionar un ejemplo?

Comment: Además, tu modelo `Reunion` cómo está asociado con `DetalleReunion`, ¿es uno a uno (i.e. `has_one`) o uno a muchos (i.e. `has_many`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay diferentes puntos que se deben corregir en tu código:

1. La validación está en el modelo equivocado, ya que quieres validar `hora_entrega`, la cual es parte del modelo `DetalleRuenion`, por lo tanto deberías mover la validación a ese modelo.
2. Utilizar el *callback* adecuado para la validación; ahora estás utilizando `before_save` para asignar `hora_pedido`, por lo que al momento de hacer la validación de `hora_entrega`, ese campo está vacío (i.e. `nil`). Para que funcione utiliza el *callback* `before_validation`.
3. Agregar la relación adecuada (i.e. `has_many`) en tu modelo `Reunion`.
4. Los nombres de tus modelos no siguen las convenciones de *ActiveRecord*, por lo que debes cambiar el nombre a tus modelos o, especificar la tabla adecuada en ellos utilizando `self.table_name` (en tu caso recomiendo esta última).
5. En el método `validar_horas` no estás incluyendo ninguna acción después del `if` (lo cual me parece correcto ya que es una validación)<sup>1</sup>, por lo que te recomiendo utilizar `unless`<sup>2</sup> en su lugar y así evitar dejar el `if` vacío.

Considerando los puntos anteriores, así se deberían ver tus modelos y tu controlador:

app/models/reunion.rb:

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord 
  self.table_name = 'reuniones' 
  before_validation :asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion

  has_many :detalles_reuniones

  def asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion
    Time.zone = "America/Bogota"
    self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
  end
end
```

app/models/detalle_reunion.rb:

```
class DetalleReunion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'detalles_reuniones' 

  validate :validar_horas
  belongs_to :reunion

  def validar_horas
    unless hora_entrega - (60 * 60 * 24) >= reunion.hora_pedido
      errors.add(:hora_entrega, "La entrega debe ser mayor a 24  horas")
    end
  end 
end
```

app/controllers/detalles_reuniones_controller.rb

```
class DetallesReunionesController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_detalle_reunion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] 

  def index 
    @detalles_reuniones = DetalleReunion.all 
  end 

  def show 
  end 

  def new 
    @detalle_reunion = DetalleReunion.new 
  end 

  def edit 
  end 

  def create 
    @detalle_reunion = DetalleReunion.new(detalle_reunion_params) 

    respond_to do |format| 
      if @detalle_reunion.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @detalle_reunion, notice: 'Detalle reunion was successfully created.' } 
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @detalle_reunion } 
      else 
        format.html { render :new } 
        format.json { render json: @detalle_reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end 
    end 
  end 

  def update 
    respond_to do |format| 
      if @detalle_reunion.update(detalle_reunion_params) 
        format.html { redirect_to @detalle_reunion, notice: 'Detalle reunion was successfully updated.' } 
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @detalle_reunion } 
      else 
        format.html { render :edit } 
        format.json { render json: @detalle_reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end 
    end 
  end 

  def destroy 
    @detalle_reunion.destroy 

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to detalles_reuniones_url, notice: 'Detalle reunion was successfully destroyed.' } 
      format.json { head :no_content } 
    end 
  end 

  private 
  def set_detalle_reunion 
    @detalle_reunion = DetalleReunion.find(params[:id]) 
  end 

  def detalle_reunion_params 
    params.require(:reunion)
          .permit(detalles_reuniones_attributes: [:hora_entrega, :cantidad, :producto_id, :valor, :evento_interno_id])
  end 
end
```

<sup>1</sup> *Esto no genera error alguno, pero por legibilidad es mejor evitar este estilo de programación*.

<sup>2</sup> *Si no te gusta `unless`, también puedes optar por cambiar la lógica del `if`*:

```
if hora_entrega - (60 * 60 * 24) < reunion.hora_pedido
  errors.add(:hora_entrega, "La entrega debe ser mayor a 24  horas")
end
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60196/discussion-on-answer-by-gerry-validar-hora-pedido-y-hora-entrega-para-que-sea-ma).

Comment: Hola no me deja  con el chat no me se pudo solucionar

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias por el chat! Tomó un poco más de tiempo pero se logró resolver la duda/problema del OP!

Comment: de nada hermano :D un gusto enorme saber que se resolvió mediante el chat, moviendo todos los comentarios queda orden en el sitio y todos felices :D Que sigan los éxitos! :D